# Why did Genesis work in this case?

Tags: plot-explanation, preacher

In *Preacher* s02e06, Jesse parts with

> 1% of his soul.

Right after the loss, in the same episode, he successfully uses Genesis to give orders to the Saint of Killers.

In the next several episodes, unless I'm overlooking something, Jesse does not try to use Genesis.

In s02e13, Jesse is surprised to find out that Genesis does not work anymore. He assumes this is because of his loss from s02e06, and becomes eager to fix the situation.

In s03e09, Jesse finally gets what he lost back. Immediately after that, Genesis starts working again, confirming the assumption.

---

If Genesis indeed does not work unless the host

> has 100% of their soul,

then **why did Genesis work when Jesse gave orders to the Saint of Killers in s02e06?**

Comment: maybe Genesis didn't want to? it seems to have a will of its own